# How to wire 2 gang smart switch with two neutral wires and wire connecting both COMM

Tags: wiring, lighting, neutral

I am finding it hard to find a diagram for my specific case. I have 2 gang light switch and I would like to replace it with a smart switch. I have attached images

Am I right in saying the left COM goes in L. The wire connecting the two COMs is discarded? The wire going into the left '1WAY' goes in L1, the right '1WAY' goes in L2. Both neutral wires go in N

Thank you in advance for any help on this

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have it.

But all 3 neutral wires go to the N terminal *only if* you're allowed to splice onward power like that. Otherwise you'll need to pigtail off the neutral splice and *oh look, a spare pigtail just became available!*

Also, sanity-check the quality of this switch.  Most multi-switches like this come straight from China and are cheap dangerous junk.  If you bought it mail order, if it came from China, or if it came from Amazon Marketplace... send it back. *CE marks are certain to be faked*, unless you bought it in a responsible bricks-and-mortar store inside the EU that has a well-managed supply chain.

It's probably OK if it has a UL or ETL (or other NRTL) stamp *with a file number*.  If it has that, that'll be the biggest mark, not CE.  Big CE = junk.